# как удалить PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql

была создана таблица *comments* но потом решил что параметр  PRIMARY KEY не нужен

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

как удалить **PRIMARY KEY** из *столбца*   **id**   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если `id` автоинкрементарное : Перед удалением ключа следует удалить свойство автоинкремента:

   ALTER TABLE comments MODIFY id INT NOT NULL
2. А потом уже сам `PRIMARY KEY` (**Ваш случай**)

   ALTER TABLE comments DROP PRIMARY KEY;